# Android Java OutputStream buffering entire file into stream

Tags: java, android, http, inputstream, outputstream

I have an app that requires loading video file from the gallery (or from camera app) into the app and then sends that video file into HTTP PUT request to a presigned S3 upload url.

My question is, when I look at the profiler on Android Studio, it seems like the HTTPURLConnection part of the code is using up a lot of memory. The increase of memory usage at that particular moment is equivalent to the size of the video file, so I assume the entire video file bytes are being loaded into memory. Here's my code snippet and what I've tried so far.
All of these trials ended up with the same memory usage results.

```
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) urls[0].openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "video/mp4");
    
    BufferedInputStream in =
            new BufferedInputStream(getActivity().getContentResolver()
                                             .openInputStream(uri));
    DataOutputStream out =
            new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    int bufferSize = 8 * 1024;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    int len = 0;
    while ((len = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
       out.write(buffer, 0, len);
       out.flush();
       // After I flush the output stream, shouldn't the out.size() be 0?
       // When I print logs here, the out stream's size keeps growing to the video file's size.
    }

    in.close();
    out.close();
```

I've also tried doing
`IOUtils.copyStream(in, out);`
I've also tried using `BufferedOutputStream` instead of `DataOutputStream`

1. From the code, why is my code loading the entire file to memory despite the fact i'm reading from the input stream 8 KB at a time?
2. When I flush the DataOutputStream, why is my OutputStream still not at 0 bytes?
3. What is the best way to achieve this for large files of over 200MB?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `// When I print logs here` I dont see you doing that.

Comment: Maybe the buffered input stream is doing that? Try without.

Comment: @blackapps Yeah I just printed logs there, but i didn't copy paste the logging code. I tried using a regular InputStream instead, but no luck

Comment: It is `HttpURLConnection` doing that, so that it can set the `Content-length` header. You can avert that by using chunked transfer mode. NB Don't flush inside loops. "After I flush the output stream, shouldn't the out.size() be 0?": no.

Comment: ... because [`DataOutputStream.size()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#size--) returns 'the number of bytes written to this data output stream so far'. Not the number of bytes currently in the buffer: in fact `DataOutputStream` doesn't *have* a buffer.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne Thanks for the comment, I'm sending a http put request to a pre-signed S3 url which doesn't allow for chunked transfer mode. So I guess this means I can't avoid ```HTTPURLConnection``` loading the entire file bytes?

Comment: If you know the size in advance you can try fixed-length transfer mode. All that does is set the Content-length header in advance, but you'd better be right about it. It doesn't need server support.